# Is the "convert to decimal form" usage of "decimate" still used?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, terminology, mathematics

Recently, I came across a page in an olden-day arithmetic book (early 20th century)

[image: There is another way of decimating, which is as follows: Decimate 1/97]

It seems that the word *decimate* was used in the sense "convert [a vulgar fraction] into a decimal fraction".
Does this  sense/usage still exist in practice in today's standard mathematics courses, or has it become outdated?

Comment: I was a student in the 1950s and 60s, and taught Maths (in Australia) into this millenium, and I have never come across the word used in this way.

Comment: The more common verb form for the action described, I believe, is _decimalize_, which is mentioned in _Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary_ (2003) in its entry for _decimalization_: "**decimalization** _n_ (1855) conversion (as of a currency) to a decimal system — **decimalize** _vt_". The _Tenth Collegiate_ does not list a comparable meaning for _decimate_ among its four definitions of that term.

Comment: I was a student in the 1950s and 60s, and taught maths (in England), and like Peter I have never come across the word used in this way. // Have you looked in any dictionaries, Sg? They add caveats such as 'obsolete' or drop unused senses.

Comment: What book is this?

Comment: By the way, [the book](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Higher_Arithmetic/CyE3AAAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&pg=PA79&printsec=frontcover) was written and published before 1850.

Comment: @SvenYargs: That's different -- that definition is about changing the system itself from a non-decimal system to a decimal system. For example, when British currency was decimalized, they switched from a system where 1 pound = 20 shillings = 240 pence to a system where 1 pound = 100 pence. (See [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimalisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimalisation).)

Comment: @ruakh: The vast majority of published instances of _decimalize_ are exactly as you say: references to changing systems of currency or physical measurement from a non-decimal system to a decimal one. On the other hand, consider this instance from [_Developing Number Knowledge: Assessment, Teaching & Intervention with 7–11 Year Olds_](https://books.google.com/books?id=64RAtmXqaVcC&pg=PA77&dq=%22decimalize%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwidx6GKx8mDAxWhLzQIHdJyBco4MhDoAXoECA0QAg#v=onepage&q=%22decimalize%22&f=false) (2012):

Comment: "As students become more proficient at incrementing and decrementing by ones, tens, and hundreds they: ... **decimalize** their approach to multi-digit numbers, habitually organizing numbers in terms of the base-ten units of ones, tens, hundreds, and so on. Such base-ten thinking is critical for numeracy." Likewise, from [_The Junior School Dictionary_](https://books.google.com/books?id=IBRUDkMrQk4C&pg=PA151&dq=%22decimalize%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwidx6GKx8mDAxWhLzQIHdJyBco4MhDoAXoECAQQAg#v=onepage&q=%22decimalize%22&f=false) (2002):

Comment: "**decimal** _adjective_ **1** based on tenths or ten: _decimal currency_ **2** able to be expressed in tenths: _a deciomal fraction_ **decimal** _noun_ **3** a fraction in which the bottom number or denominator is 19, 100, 1000, 10 000 and so on, but which is usually written with just the top number after a dot or decimal point, as in _0.5 = 5/10_ or _0.05 = 5/100_" **_Word Family_** **decimalize** or **decimalise** _verb_ to express in decimals **decimally** _adverb_." As I said in my original comment, I think that _decimalize_ is the more common form used to express this idea today.

Comment: Finally, I note that _The American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language_, fifth edition (2010) has a separate entry for _decimalize_, with a very broad definition: "**decimalize** _tr.v._ To change to a decimal system." This definition seems to apply as fully to conversion of a purely numerical system (as from halves, quarters, and eighths) to decimals as to conversion of a currency or a system of measurement to decimals.

Comment: Obligatory joke that in Britain, decimalization  in 1971 meant eliminating usage of *LSD*...

Answer (score 28):

RIP *decimate*. (It’s obsolete in that sense.)

> **decimate** *verb*
> **3.** † *transitive*. To divide (something) into tenths, or into tenths, hundredths, and so on; to decimalize. *Obsolete*.
> [1678–1875]
>  <sub>Source: [*Oxford English
> Dictionary*](https://oed.com) (login required)</sub>

Comment: *decimate* "(6) (**obsolete**) To divide into tenths; to **decimalize**." https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/decimate - no login required.

Answer (score 0):

Idiomatically (and this may be BrE) **decimation** is the act of killing one in ten soldiers of an army. I believe this usage is not obsolete.

> In the military of ancient Rome, decimation (from Latin decimatio 'removal of a tenth'[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimation_(punishment))) was a form of military discipline in which every tenth man in a group was executed by members of his cohort.

[Wikipedia - decimation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimation_(punishment))

**Decimilisation** was what occurred in the UK when we lost 12 pennies to the shilling and gained 100 pennies to the pound and ended up unable to divide anything by three.

This also dates back to Roman times :

> Prior to 1971, there were 12 pennies to the shilling and 20 shillings to the pound. There were guineas, half crowns, threepenny bits, sixpences and florins. This old system of currency, known as pounds, shillings and pence or lsd, dated back to Roman times.

[The History of Decimilisation](https://www.historic-uk.com/HistoryUK/HistoryofBritain/Decimalisation-in-Britain/)

Comment: Outside of Roman military history, the sense ‘killing one in ten soldiers of an army’ is pretty much obsolete. It’s so exceedingly rare that you need to talk about it that no one ever actually uses it that way in practice. Decimation nowadays primarily refers to reducing (the strength of) something to a small fraction(!) of what it used to be through hostile means.

Comment: Yes, modern usage has flipped this so that "decimate" is closer to destroying 90% of the thing in question rather than 10%.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet That is an interesting thought. Have you a source for that ?

Comment: @NigelJ Most of the dictionaries I’ve just checked give the looser meaning first (some with a note that this use is proscribed by some), which should indicate that they consider this the most common usage; some relegate the military use to a specifically historical/Roman context. If you look at [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/decimate), they show what looks like five different sources, only one of which has the ‘one in ten’ meaning first. [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/decimate) also notes that ‘devastate’ is now the more common sense.